# Using Dictionary, How do I display multiple most common numbers using .Max c# winforms

Tags: c#, winforms

How do I display the common number? but if other numbers are just as common, I want to be able to display multiple.

So I have an array with a max length of 24, I can generate random number between 1-100 and sort them.

Looks something like this..
2
8
9
10
13
19
20
38
43
47
51
55
55
59
66
67
73
84
87
87
93
95
98
100

So the most common numbers are 55 and 87, as 55 and 87 show up twice.

Here's my code..

```
private void buttonMode_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int mode = 0;
    int max = 0;
    var counts = new Dictionary<int, int>();
    foreach (int value in dataArray)
    {
        if (counts.ContainsKey(value))
        {
            counts[value]++;
        }
        else
        {
            counts.Add(value, 1);
        }
    }

    foreach(KeyValuePair<int,int> count in counts)
    {
        if (count.Value > max)
        {
            mode = count.Key;
            max = count.Value;
        }
    }
    textBoxOut1.Text = $"Mode is: {mode}";
}
```

This only displays the lowest common value, which using the example above would be 55 only.
I've searched and by using .Max this can be done, but how?

Comment: Don't store the mode in the second loop, only the max. Add a third loop to search for all modes, which have the same max.

Comment: Did I get you right that you are looking for all duplicates?

Comment: Most common number, problem is what if the most common number is 2 or 3  numbers, if they all show up the same amount of times.

Comment: @SergeyKalinichenko Still trying to figure out how I can do that, really new to programming. Will update this once I figure it out. But thanks, that made sense.

Comment: @Gilli Make sure `mode` is a collection or a string, not an `int`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Offering a non-LINQ method here. We'll keep track of individual number frequencies in a `Dictionary<int, int>` and then also keep track of the maximum frequency we've seen so far and any numbers with that frequency. This approach will allow us to do everything in a single pass over the source data.

```cs
// Initialize the test data
int[] values = "2 8 9 10 13 19 20 38 43 47 51 55 55 59 66 67 73 84 87 87 93 95 98 100".Split(' ').Select(int.Parse).ToArray();

// Prepare our frequency tracking dictionary, max frequency count, and frequent values set
var frequencyTrack = new Dictionary<int, int>();
int maxCount = 0;
var mostFrequentValues = new HashSet<int>();

foreach (int val in values)
{
    int curCount = 1;
    // If we already know about this number then we should
    // update the frequency to existing + 1
    if (frequencyTrack.TryGetValue(val, out int existingCount))
    {
        curCount = existingCount + 1;
    }
    // set the frequency for this value
    frequencyTrack[val] = curCount;

    // if the frequency is higher than the previously known value
    // we have a new winner, so we should record the new frequency
    // and clear the winning list of numbers before finally adding
    // the current value
    if (curCount > maxCount)
    {
        maxCount = curCount;
        mostFrequentValues.Clear();
        mostFrequentValues.Add(val);
    }
    // if the count matches the current max then we should
    // add it as another winner
    else if (curCount == maxCount)
    {
        mostFrequentValues.Add(val);
    }
    // we don't care about lesser frequencies so we don't do anything here
}

// print the result(s)
Console.WriteLine("{0} appear(s) {1} time(s)", string.Join(", ", mostFrequentValues), maxCount);
```

Output:

> 55, 87 appear(s) 2 time(s)

[Try it online](https://rextester.com/RXGV60001)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `GroupBy`, one for the `int`-value and the other for the group-sizes:

```
List<List<int>> maxGroups = dataArray
    .GroupBy(i => i)                           // group by int-value
    .GroupBy(g => g.Count(), g => g.ToList())  // group groups by size
    .OrderByDescending(g => g.Key)             // get biggest group
    .First()
    .ToList();
```

This gives you a list with two sub-lists, each contain 2 integers, one 55 and the other 87.

If you want to use your counts-dictionary, you could use this:

```
int maxCount = counts.Values.Max();
List<(int value, int count)> maxValueCounts = counts
    .Where(kv => kv.Value == maxCount)
    .Select(kv => (kv.Key, kv.Value))
    .ToList();
```

Here you get a list with the max-count values in a named tuple.

Comment: The element selector in the second GroupBy has to be `g.First()`? Otherwise you will get as result a list of elements.

Comment: @Caveman74: the second groupby selects the integers into a `List<int>`. So in this case you get a list that contains two lists, the first list contains two 55 and the second list contains two 87. The advantage is, you have the value, you have the count and you have a sub-list(if needed). My second approach shows a way to just select the value and the count.

Answer (score 0):

You could use 'textBoxOut1.Text += mode + ", "' in you 2nd foreach.

Hint: To make the code easier to debug and read, separate it into multiple functions : 'List CountOccurences(List list)' and 'List FindTopMostCommon(List list)' (Or what ever you like for naming).

Or short it all down to Linq as Time suggested

Answer (score 0):

You could also replace the `foreach` on the `counts` dictionary with the following code:

```
var modes = counts.Where(count => count.Value == counts.Values.Max());
var output = string.Join(", ", modes.Select(c => c.Key.ToString()));
textBoxOut1.Text = $"Mode is: {output}";
```

Answer (score 0):

In my solution you don't need to write any loops.

```
var dict = dataArray.GroupBy(x => x)
                .ToDictionary(x => x.Key, x => x.Count());
var max = dict.Values.Max();
var modes = dict.Where(x => x.Value == max)
                .Select(x => x.Key);
```

Comment: You don't need to _write_ any loops, sure.